# A doubt in Bergman's notes

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, universal-algebra

On pg. 8 of [these notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.0.pdf), Bergman says that a group $G$ contains an inverse operation $i:G\to G$, along with $\mu:G\times G\to G$ and a "neutral element" $e$. Hence, a group should be referred to as $(|G|,\mu,i,e)$.

Is there really an inverse operation? I thought an inverse is an element such that $\mu(a,a^{-1})=e$.

Is there really any need to mention a group as $(|G|,\mu,i,e)$, when just $(|G|,\mu)$ will do perfectly?

Comment: @rschwieb- Because mentioning just $|G|$ wouldn't give any information about the group operation.

Comment: but mentioning "just $|G|$ and $\mu$" wouldn't give any information about the inverse operation or the identity element. Now I guess you can see that deeming what is "necessary" in the notation is subjective!

Comment: @rschwieb (and user4894): Points granted (though "any English verb can be nouned"), and I think your comments do isolate the specific difference in idiom: It's rarely used as a noun in the singular, and it's used to express cautious disagreement/challenge rather than simply to request more information. (I took offense at that implication the first few times I heard it, until I realized that it was just an English-to-English translation problem.)

Answer (score 7):

Notice that when you said

> an inverse is an element such that $μ(a,a^{−1})=e$.

you are using the notation $a^{-1}$ without having defined it.  What, exactly, does $a^{-1}$ mean?
One of the axioms of a group is that

> for each element $a$, there exists an element $b$ such that $\mu(a,b) = \mu(b,a) = e$.

By [skolemizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolemization) this existence statement, we obtain the equivalent statement:

> there is a *function* $i$ with the property that
>   for each element $a$, we have $\mu(a, i(a)) = \mu(i(a), a) = e$

and we conventionally denote $i(a)$ as $a^{-1}$.  This is the definition of the $a^{-1}$ notation.

In informal treatments, we leave all this implicit, but the idea is still there: whenever you write ‘$a^{-1}$’ you are implicitly assuming the existence of a function that maps each $a$ to its inverse.  Until you construct such a function, your use of the notation $a^{-1}$ is unjustified.

Comment: Thank you. The concept of Skolemizing addresses the question perfectly.

Comment: I think skolemize will become a new favorite mathbabble term of mine :)

Comment: It is one of my favorites too.  You may also want to observe that $e$ itself is an example of what is known as a *Skolem constant*.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that since the neutral element and the inverse are unique in a group, they need not be mentioned (they are properties of the multiplication rather than really distinguished elements). But it can still be practical to single out these two things, as they are after all there, and when generalizing the concept of a group to that of a group-element in a category, they become important.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so saying that $G$ is a group having the operation $\mu$ implicitly gives us an inverse map and a neutral element, so we can just drop $i$ and $e$. But why stop there? Why not just say that saying "$G$ is a group" implicitly gives us an operation, and therefore writing $\mu$ is superfluous? Of course, this is perfectly fine, especially if you never intend to write $\mu$.

The point is that the usefulness of a notation is dictated by the usage the author intends. In something like a universal algebra book, expressing all four pieces of data in compact notation like this is the best thing to serve their needs. In another book, another author may use a slimmed down version because it suits his/her purposes just fine. You *can* do that provided that the context you're in does not admit chances for confusion.

If you intend to talk about a semigroup $S$ and/or a monoid $M$ in the same context, then you'd probably want to adopt similar notations like $(|S|,\mu_S)$ and $(|M|,\mu_M,1_M)$, and one can tell, at a glance, all of the important specified data.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen My whole point is that statements like the one you're making are subjective judgments about what is "enough." Yes, you can infer what the neutral element is and what the inverses are from $\mu$. But another could argue that $\mu$ is superfluous and all you need to say is that $G$ is a group, infer the existence of the operation from this statement. All I'm saying is that the level of specificity is determined by the needs of the authors, and the needs of the authors are pretty high in a book on universal algebra. See what I mean? (In fact, this seems worth adding to the answer.)

Comment: Dear @IlmariKaronen : The question is not about defining $G$: the OP is asking why the author is taking pains with so much notation. It's a good question: such bulky notation is not normally warranted. It is a little repulsive, but knowing a little bit about Bergman's work, I'm sure he's a good judge about how to write :)

Comment: Hmm, clearly you're reading something very different into the OP's question than I am. Not being a mindreader, I cannot really disprove your interpretation of the question (unless the OP clarifies their intent), even if it may seem unlikely to me (but then, I'm probably biased here), so we should probably just agree that we're answering different questions, and leave it at that.

Comment: Dear @IlmariKaronen : That could certainly be possible and this seems like a perfectly fine resolution :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there really is an inverse operation in a group.  Remember that you don't just need to have a single inverse $x^{-1}$ for some arbitrary $x$, but an inverse for *every* $x \in |G|$.  Given these inverses, we can define a function $\iota: |G| \to |G|$ as $\iota(x) = x^{-1}$, and this $\iota$ is precisely the operation that, applied to any element of the group, gives its inverse.

As for your second question, if you scroll down to page 9, you'll find the following note by Bergman that directly addresses it:

> There is another denition of group that you have probably also seen: In effect, a group is defined to be a pair $(|G|,\cdot)$, such that $G$ is a set, and $\cdot$ is a map $|G|\times|G|\to|G|$ satisfying $$ (\forall x,y,z \in |G|)\ (x \cdot y)\cdot z = x \cdot (y \cdot z), \\  \tag{1.2.2} (\exists e \in |G|)\ ((\forall x \in |G|)\ e \cdot x = x = x \cdot e) \land \\ \hspace{9em} ((\forall x \in |G|)\ (\exists y \in |G|)\ y \cdot x = e = x \cdot y). $$
>
> It is easy to show that given $(|G|,\cdot)$ satisfying (1.2.2), there exist a unique operation $^{-1}$ and a unique element $e$ such that $(|G|,\cdot, \,^{-1}, e)$ satisfies (1.2.1). (Remember the lemmas saying that neutral elements and 2-sided inverses are unique when they exist.) Thus, these two versions of the concept of group provide equivalent information. Our description using 4-tuples may seem "uneconomical" compared with one using pairs, but we will stick with it. We shall eventually see that, more important than the number of terms in the tuple, is the fact that condition (1.2.1) consists of identities, i.e., universally quantified equations, while (1.2.2) does not. But we will at times acknowledge the idea of the second definition; for instance, when we ask (imprecisely) whether some semigroup "is a group".